# How to get number of attributes in a table

Tags: mysql

How to get number of attributes in a table using mysql. I want to get how many colums in a table.

Comment: you can use desc tablename;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to actually query the `information_schema` table. The following should achieve what you're looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `columns`
FROM `information_schema`.`columns`
WHERE `table_schema` = 'database_name' 
  AND `table_name` = 'tablename'
```